# what is suppressPowerOn and suppressPowerOff option in vim-cmd?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-esx

I was tinkering with vim-cmd for reverting snapshots and wondering what these `suppressPowerOn` and `suppressPowerOn` options are for ?

I tried both options and makes no difference (vm is in powered off state). This snapshot with `id 2` was taken without enabling "snapshotting vm memory" and "Quiesce guest file system"

```
[root@localhost:/opt] /bin/vim-cmd vmsvc/snapshot.revert 10 2 suppressPowerOff
Revert Snapshot:
|-ROOT
--Snapshot Name        : server 6.0.1
--Snapshot Id        : 2
--Snapshot Desciption  : test server
--Snapshot Created On  : 2/16/2018 10:48:53
--Snapshot State       : powered off

[root@localhost:/opt] /bin/vim-cmd vmsvc/snapshot.revert 10 2 suppressPowerOn
Revert Snapshot:
|-ROOT
--Snapshot Name        : server 6.0.1
--Snapshot Id        : 2
--Snapshot Desciption  : test server
--Snapshot Created On  : 2/16/2018 10:48:53
--Snapshot State       : powered off
```

Answer (score 0):

If `suppressPowerOn` is set to `true`, the virtual machine will not be powered on regardless of the power state when the current snapshot was created.

Default to `false`.